# Fade in /Fade out in Ext.window

Tags: extjs

I am using

```
var  modalWindow = new Ext.Window({
title: "Window",
items: [
    {html: "<div id='example'>Hello</div> "}
]
});
modalWindow.show();
```

to open a modal window. I need fadein/fadeout features on this window. 
Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    var  modalWindow = new Ext.Window({
        title: "Window",
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        html: "<div id='example'>Hello</div> ",
        listeners : {
            show : function(window) {
                window.getEl().setOpacity(0);
                window.getEl().fadeIn({duration: 2000});
            },
            beforeclose : function(window) {
                if(!window.shouldClose) {
                    window.getEl().fadeOut({duration: 2000, callback: function() {
                        window.shouldClose = true;
                        window.close();
                    }});
                }
                return window.shouldClose ? true : false;
            }
        }

    });
    modalWindow.show();
```

Comment: can you explain window.getEl() as i am trying to understand the code.. I am not getting what exactly is getting passed as argument in show function

Comment: I had to proceed differently because I wanted that some windows inherit this behavior. So I use the Window initComponent function, and inside this function I have :
`var me = this;
me.callParent( arguments );
me.on( "beforeclose", function( window, eOpts ) { // same code});`

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq Many options there, you could override the `Window` close method. But if you are sticking with adding a listener to your `initComponent`, remember that there is no need to pass `arguments` to callParent within that method.